# How can I hide the parent div of a checkbox if the checkbox is not checked?

Tags: jquery

if my checkbox with the class `box` is not checked I want to hide the div with the class `checkbox`. But not all divs with the class `checkbox`. Only the parent div of the unchecked checkbox. This is my try. But it hides only the box not the whole div:

```
<div class="checkbox"><input class="box" type="checkbox" name="green" value="green">green</div>

  $("input.box:checkbox:not(:checked)").css({"display": "none"});
```

I hope I explained it more or less understandable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this using jQuery [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/):

```
$("input.box:checkbox:not(:checked)").closest('.checkbox').hide();
```

Comment: Great answer! An alternative would be: `$("input.box:checkbox:not(:checked)").parent().hide();`

Comment: @PeterKA Thanks! I think you are right. `parent` will also work as it selects one element up the DOM tree, but I try to avoid it in some cases as sometimes programmers get confused between `parents` & `parent`.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use the [`:has`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector:

```
$(".checkbox:has(input.box:checkbox:not(:checked))").hide();
```

(Note: [`.hide`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) is equivalent to setting it to display none)

Comment: Also working! Now I cannot deside which is the better solution

Comment: @Jarla I would use `.closest` for this task. I like the readability that `:has` offers, but it can cause issues if you have nested `.checkbox`'s.

Answer (score 1):

Try using as

```
$(function(){
  $('input[class="box"][type="checkbox"]').not(":checked").parent().css({"display": "none"});

});
```

[Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/gbw1pg56/)

Comment: A good answer but I would be very careful with `[class=...]`, especially if there's a likelihood of there being other classes. `.box` is recommended.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input:checkbox").not(":checked").closest('.checkbox').hide();
```